# How to present/display html formatted text inside my app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, richtextbox

So I have created a react notepad. I used `react` for front-end, and `node js` + `mongodb` as back-end. And then I added [react-quill](https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/) to have rich text editor inside my app.

The thing is that I integrated this text editor to my project, and now I can input data with html styling to my database, but I don't know what part of that `react-quill` should I use to display my notes data that are fetched from the server to my app.

Could you help me with that?

Here is [react-quill github page](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill), and here is [react-quill documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#content).

It is hard for me to find that particular info inside this documentation, maybe I'm not experienced enough.

For now, I'm stuck with this:

[image]

And here is my `NoteNew` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNote } from '../actions/actions';

class NoteNew extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: '',
    };
  }

  handleContentChange(value) {
    this.setState({ content: value });
  }

  onSumbit(values) {
    const content = this.state.content;
    const currentTime = this.formatDateAndHour();
    const currentTimeRaw = new Date();
    this.props.addNote(
      { ...values, content, createTime: currentTime, timeRaw: currentTimeRaw },
      () => this.props.history.push('/')
    );
  }

  formatDateAndHour() {
    const monthNames = [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December',
    ];
    const date = new Date();
    const day = date.getDate();
    const monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const hour = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const dayShow = day < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;
    const hourShow = hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : hour;
    const minutesShow = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
    return `${dayShow} ${
      monthNames[monthIndex]
    } ${year} ${hourShow}:${minutesShow}`;
  }

  errorView() {
    const { addNoteStatus } = this.props;
    if (addNoteStatus === 'error') {
      return (
        <div className="error-del">
          Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div />;
  }

  renderFieldTitle(field) {
    const className = `form-group ${
      field.meta.touched && field.meta.error ? 'has-danger' : ''
    }`;
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label className="form-title" htmlFor="title">
          {field.labelToShow}
        </label>
        <br />
        <input className="form-control-title" type="text" {...field.input} />
        <div className="text-help">
          {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="row form-fields text-center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSumbit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            name="title"
            labelToShow="Note title"
            component={this.renderFieldTitle}
          />
          <ReactQuill
            value={this.state.content}
            onChange={this.handleContentChange.bind(this)}
            name="content"
            labelToShow="content"
            component={this.renderFieldContent}
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary submit-button">
            <i className="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" />
          </button>
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-secondary back-button">
            <i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" />
          </Link>
          {this.errorView()}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.title || values.title.length < 3) {
    errors.title = 'Enter note title that is at least 3 characters long!';
  }
  return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    addNoteStatus: state.addNoteStatus,
  };
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'NoteNewFormUnique',
})(connect(mapStateToProps, { addNote })(NoteNew));
```

And here is my `NoteShow` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { prepareEdit, deleteOneNote } from '../actions/actions';

class NoteShow extends Component {
  onEditClick() {
    const { selectedNoteFromState } = this.props;
    this.props.prepareEdit(selectedNoteFromState, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/notes/edit');
    });
  }

  onDeleteClick() {
    const { selectedNoteFromState } = this.props;
    this.props.deleteOneNote(selectedNoteFromState, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }

  errorView() {
    const { delNoteStatus } = this.props;
    if (delNoteStatus === 'error') {
      return (
        <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 error-del text-center">
          Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div />;
  }

  timeView() {
    const { selectedNoteFromState } = this.props;
    const { allNotesFromStateObj } = this.props;
    const noteToView = allNotesFromStateObj[selectedNoteFromState];
    if (noteToView.editTime) {
      return (
        <p className="text-center date-time">
          Last edited: {noteToView.editTime}
        </p>
      );
    }
    return (
      <p className="text-center date-time">Created: {noteToView.createTime}</p>
    );
  }

  renderNoteDetail() {
    const { selectedNoteFromState } = this.props;
    const { allNotesFromStateObj } = this.props;
    const noteToView = allNotesFromStateObj[selectedNoteFromState];
    return (
      <div className="col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 pull-sm-right text-justify note-show">
        <h2 className="text-center">{noteToView.title}</h2>
        <p className="note-text">{noteToView.content}</p>
        <hr />
        {this.timeView()}
        <button
          className="btn btn-secondary pull-xs-left small-buttons"
          onClick={this.onEditClick.bind(this)}
        >
          <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" />
        </button>
        <button
          className="btn btn-secondary pull-xs-right small-buttons"
          onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)}
        >
          <i className="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { statusFromState } = this.props;
    const { selectedNoteFromState } = this.props;
    if (
      statusFromState === 'fetch_all_notes_success' &&
      selectedNoteFromState !== null
    ) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.renderNoteDetail()}
          {this.errorView()}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div />;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    selectedNoteFromState: state.selectedNote,
    statusFromState: state.fetchAllStatus,
    allNotesFromStateObj: state.notes,
    delNoteStatus: state.delNoteStatus,
  };
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { prepareEdit, deleteOneNote })(NoteShow)
);
```

Comment: `onSumbit` is a funny method name! +1 Actually I wasn't able to find any bits to sum in your application at first glance. Have I missed something?

Comment: Are you asking specifically for a react-quill solution? Because there's a few questions on SO about this: [Rendering raw html with reactjs](//stackoverflow.com/q/27934238)

Comment: @connexo hmm, I'm not very good at naming methods, sorry...